# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@cycle/run' webpack 2.2.1

Tags: javascript, npm, webpack-2

I'm trying to run a hello world app in [cycle.js](https://cycle.js.org/getting-started.html) using webpack 2.2.1

I'm getting this error:

> ERROR in ./app/index.js Module not found: Error: Can't resolve
>   '@cycle/run' in '/Users/Ben/proj/sb_vol_calc/frontend/app'  @
>   ./app/index.js 7:11-32  @ multi
>   webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:3000 ./app/index

Here is my webpack.config.js:

```
   var path = require('path')
var webpack = require('webpack')

module.exports = {
  devtool: 'eval',
  entry: [
    'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:3000',
    './app/index'
  ],
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader'
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js'],
    modules: [
      path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
      "node_modules"
    ]
  }
}
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "xxx",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "es2015",
      "react",
      "stage-0"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.23.1",
    "babel-loader": "^6.3.2",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.22.0",
    "webpack": "^2.2.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.4.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@cycle/dom": "^14.3.0",
    "@cycle/xstream-run": "^4.2.0",
    "xstream": "^10.2.0"
  }
}
```

I have run npm install. Is it just supposed to work now? Or am I missing something?

index.js:

```
import xs from 'xstream';
import {run} from '@cycle/run';
import {makeDOMDriver, h1} from '@cycle/dom';

function main() {
  const sinks = {
    DOM: xs.periodic(1000).map(i =>
      h1('' + i + ' seconds elapsed')
    )
  };
  return sinks;
}

const drivers = {
  DOM: makeDOMDriver('#root')
};

run(main, drivers);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have `@cycle/run` installed as a dependency, but `@cycle/xstream-run`. So you would have to import `run` from it:

```
import {run} from '@cycle/xstream-run';
```

According to the [latest release](https://cycle.js.org/releases.html) `@cycle/xstream-run` has been renamed to `@cycle/run`, so you probably should start using it. All you need to do is install it:

```
npm install --save @cycle/run
```